# How to track all screens in an iOS App using Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

What are the different possible approaches of doing it?

Comment: Unless you redirect all screen presentation or all UINavigationController delegate methods to the AppDelegate there is no way to do that. Also doing it in an extension or custom UIViewControlle class is better way.

Comment: I heard it from someone that it can be done in Android. Is it true? @rckoenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it:

1. **Inheriting `GAITrackedViewController`** for all the viewcontrollers and then setting `screenName` property.
2. **Extension of UIViewController** with the following function:

   ```
   func trackScreenView() {
       let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
       tracker?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)))
       tracker?.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [NSObject : AnyObject]?)
   }
   ```